# Multisampling on iOS can't get depth texture?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I have set up rendering to a framebuffer with color and depth textures on iOS, all works ok. I then tried to add multisampling via APPLE extensions (I used this code [Rendering to texture on iOS OpenGL ES—works on simulator, but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313734/rendering-to-texture-on-ios-opengl-esworks-on-simulator-but-not-on-device/7385548#7385548) ) but there's a catch apparently.

After resolving the multisampled buffer into my original framebuffer (which I use for post processing effects), I only have the color buffer resolved. glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE() apparently does not touch my depth texture at all, so if I use multisampling I have to give up on my depth texture effects. Is there no way to get the depth texture if I use multisampling ? I know how multisampling works, I just want a depth texture alongside the color texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a couple more days of looking into this matter, I got my answer.
So the APPLE extension exists (and is different from the EXT one) just because it only resolves color. The GL ES 3.0 Standard (Probably coming to iOS 7.1) or DesktopGL says that in order to resolve Color or Depth you use glBlitFramebuffer which copies and resolves things. I tried it with DesktopGL 4.2 and blitting the depth buffer works.

I also went back to my DirectX11 renderer and tried the same thing with a GPU that Supports DirectX 11.1 level features and I was surprised that leading edge hardware can't do that in a single resolve call. ID3D11DeviceContext::ResolveSubresource throws errors when you try to resolve textures bound as depth. The workaround is to either have a special shader pass that does the depth resolving, but that implies using Texture2DMS ( A DirectX 10_1 level feature ) or to ping-pong the texture through 2 separate textures that are not bound to depth (implies 1 resolve call and 2 full depth texture copies).

Using the same counterpart in GL means using glTexImage2DMultisample images instead of multisampled renderbuffers (part of Desktop OpenGL 3.1) and then using sampler2DMS in a pixel shader for the actual shader texel fetch.

EDIT: Whether or not glBlitFramebuffer resolves depth seems to be marked as implementation dependent. On desktop GL (HD7850) it works, on GLES3 it still doesn't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Spec on `APPLE_framebuffer_multisample` tells that `glResolveMultisampleFramebufferApple` resolves color attachment, this means that you will have to write depth to color renderbuffer in additional render pass and resolve it to get depth information.

Comment: This is DX9 style and if you have a lot of polygons in your scene, rendering everything twice will kill performance fast, especially on a mobile device. I'm looking for a DX10+ style where I can fetch what's already in the driver, or rather where I can tell the driver what to resolve where (multisampled color to color and multisampled depth to depth). At least GL ES 3 will standardize multiple render targets so what you're saying can be done without a secondary pass.